# Xirsys turn server fails to connect and PeerServer crashes

Tags: node.js, peerjs, xirsys

My WebRTC application is working but sometimes when I try to call from other machines, iceServerConnectionState gets disconnected. Also, my peer server gets crashed by showing error:
     `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input`
I am using Xirsys for stun/turn and running a custom peer server built-in Nodejs. Can anyone tell what can be the reason and how to solve it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks like two separate issues.  The peer server issue looks like a signalling error.  If I were to guess, I would assume the websocket library isn't buffering correctly and so, when it comes to parsing the packet body from JSON to an object, it doesn't contain the full body required to successfully complete.

The disconnection issue is likely due to bandwidth at one of the two ends, but without some network traffic data (like a pcap capture -- wireshark), then it's not easy to diagnose.

Comment: Thanks, Lee! I am dually checking the string before using it. But, I am checking only if `confStr.d` is _null_ or _undefined_. Am I missing something? If yes, Please assist.

Comment: I doesn't look like a configuration issue, to me.  The disconnection issue looks like a bandwidth problem, while the other issue is a websocket issue, I believe.  See what your websocket has sent when that error occurs and look to see if it is a complete JSON packet.